# Socket.io with Android and Swift

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, swift, socket.io

I have a connection between an iPhone and a node.js server. Here I build a list with key/value-pairs (Dictionary) and emit it over the socket.io connection.
On the server I can access on the data, like on a normal javascript object.

```
self.socket.emit("event", ["key" : value]);
```

Now I tried in Android to send a HashMap also over a socket.io connection, but the server only receive the string "{key=value}" and I have to convert the string to an object.

```
   Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
   dict.put("key", "value");
   mSocket.emit("event", dict);
```

Is it possible to send a HashMap (or similar) and receive it in javascript as an object like in swift?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: DO you mean you want to send it via JSON?  If so, use a JSONObject, not a HashMap.

Comment: I have tried it via JSON, but it is not possible to emit JSON in Swift, because SocketIO for Swift doesn't support complex JSON. So I needed another way to emit the data and I had to use the Dictionary in Swift. But for Android I am looking for a similar solution.